# Append Title by TagManager

Tags: insert, google-tag-manager, title

Is it possible to append a Metatitle by using Google TagManager?

Ive tried several times but it does not work - probably i had the wrong scripts.

It's all about adding / changing existing Titles with a introduced character

Do you know a method or a script that makes it work

Current:

XYZ John Doe

Target:

▷ XYZ John Doe

Answer (score 0):

Would be much easier to help you if you share with us script you already have (and tag configuration). But the simplest way could be creating custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager and add:

```
<script>    
window.document.title = "▷ " + window.document.title;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - but the script doesnt work - the site doesnt change the title

Comment: in preview mode it works - but after the live rollout we have no change on the page